# Two different expression result in c# and excel

Tags: c#, excel

I find something really weird, if I used below expression in excel and c# I get different results.

```
(1) ^ (-12)
```

Excel gives 1 and c# gives -11.

Which one is right one?

Comment: It depends on you. What result are you looking for? Power?

Comment: Neither, the correct answer is 42.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're both right, because `^` means different things in different contexts.

In C# it's the [bitwise XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx).

In Excel it's the ["power" operator](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Operators.html) used to raise one number to the power of another (x<sup>y</sup>).

Answer (score 19):

In Excel `^` means exponentiation. In C# it means bitwise exclusive or. They are completely different operations; it is just a coincidence that they use the same symbol.

Use `Math.Pow` for exponentiation in C#.

Answer (score 6):

Well, mathematically the correct answer is 1.

The circumflex (^) is a logical XOR operator in C# ([see the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)), which results in 11.

To raise `x` to the power `y` in c#, use `Math.Pow(x, y)`.